# jquery each function to replace an existing html content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace the text inside all the p tags which has a particular class. My html code is

```
<p class="fb-question">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {{2fill}} ea eos eirmod dissentiet efficiantur. Porro facilisi pericula vim id.</p>
<p class="fb-question">tempor verear eum no. Facer {{2fill}} assum ut eos. Odio mutat vis ad.</p>
<p class="fb-question">Liber noster ei cum. Sed {{2fill}} an electram comprehensam, at hendrerit urbanitas eam,</p>
<p class="fb-question">etiam minimum mentitum cu {{2fill}} cum, ea rebum legimus utroque nam.</p>
```

and scripts

```
jQuery('.fb-question').each(function(){ 
    jQuery(this).html().replace('{{2fill}}', '<span id="blank"></span>');
});
```

but the issue is that the scripts are not going inside the each function even though the html class is present.
Can someone tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: I'm sure there's a dupe of this out there somewhere...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is because you're replacing the value, but you don't do anything with the result. You need to set it back to the `html()` method:

```
$('.fb-question').each(function(){ 
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('{{2fill}}', '<span id="blank"></span>'));
});
```

Or better yet, you can give the `html()` method a function to be run on each element, and avoid the use of `each()` completely:

```js
$('.fb-question').html(function(i, h){ 
  return h.replace('{{2fill}}', '<span id="blank"></span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="fb-question">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {{2fill}} ea eos eirmod dissentiet efficiantur. Porro facilisi pericula vim id.</p>
<p class="fb-question">tempor verear eum no. Facer {{2fill}} assum ut eos. Odio mutat vis ad.</p>
<p class="fb-question">Liber noster ei cum. Sed {{2fill}} an electram comprehensam, at hendrerit urbanitas eam,</p>
<p class="fb-question">etiam minimum mentitum cu {{2fill}} cum, ea rebum legimus utroque nam.</p>
```

Comment: as other option -   jquery `replaceAll` or `replaceWith` function, which doesn't require seting new html to element

Comment: @demo true, but that involves removing the original element from the DOM and creating a new one, which will be slower, and would also disconnect any existing event handlers on those elements.

Comment: didn't know that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The `innerHTML` value is a string type and it is immutable. So the `replace` method;

```
var str = "myString";
str.replace("my","your");
```

won't mutate `str` however it will return a new one. So, in this particular case you are expected to do like;

```
str = str.replace("my","your");
```

On the other hand without jQuery you can always do this with pure JS very simply;

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".fb-question")
        .forEach(p => p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace('{{2fill}}', '<span id="blank"></span>'));
```

```html
<p class="fb-question">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {{2fill}} ea eos eirmod dissentiet efficiantur. Porro facilisi pericula vim id.</p>
<p class="fb-question">tempor verear eum no. Facer {{2fill}} assum ut eos. Odio mutat vis ad.</p>
<p class="fb-question">Liber noster ei cum. Sed {{2fill}} an electram comprehensam, at hendrerit urbanitas eam,</p>
<p class="fb-question">etiam minimum mentitum cu {{2fill}} cum, ea rebum legimus utroque nam.</p>
```